# error 500 deploy laravel 5.7 php 7.1.3 vps digitalocean

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

php:error] [pid 435305] [client 109.108.91.72:53224] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:838\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(838): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()\n#1 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(807): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies()\n#2 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()\n#3 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()\n#4 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(759): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()\n#5 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(264): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()\n#6 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}()\n#7 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build()\n#8 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()\n#9 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(759): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()\n#10 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(159): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()\n#11 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(112): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->getExceptionHandler()\n#12 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse()\n#13 /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(123): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException()\n#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()\n#15 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/file/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 838

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKkup.png)

[error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EILhm.png)

[virtual host config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYqGc.png)

Comment: Please don't just dump an error and expect people to help you. Take the time and give us enough information. That said, this is a standard error when you're running a PHP version that doesn't support the Laravel version you're running. Laravel 5.7 and PHP 7.1.3 are compatible so please double check if indeed you are running those versions. Remember, there can be multiple PHP versions running including an interpreter for the web and CLI.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: VM114:6774 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.